# Is it possible to take a screenshot of a dashboard in OS X?

Tags: screen-capture, dashboard

I'm using a  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>5</kbd>  command to take a screenshot of a desktop, but it doesn't work if I switch to the dashboard.

Is there any way to take a screenshot of dashboard elements?

Comment: I can't reproduce this on OS X Yosemite (I can take screenshots using ⇧⌘3 and ⇧⌘4 (⇧⌘5 is not a default shortcut). What version of OS X are you using? Are you using Dashboard as a space or overlay?

Comment: cmd shift 5 is the default for Skitch and Captured are you using either of those?

Comment: @dstarh I use Skitch, but Cmd + Shift + 4 worked for me (see the answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you set up  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>5</kbd>  yourself, as it's not a System default.

If you use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>4</kbd>  then you can drag a marquee round the item you want, or even use  <kbd>Space</kbd>  afterwards to grab the entire floating widget, examples below…

1. Using  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>4</kbd> 
   Note the hard edges & visible background.
   [image]
2. Using  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>4</kbd>   followed by  <kbd>Space</kbd>  then clicking the desired 'window'/widget.
   Note the soft edges with shadows
   [image]

Comment: Cmd+Shift+5 is the sequence used by [Captured](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/captured/id414675451?mt=12) -- a popular screen capture and auto-share tool for OS X. They might be using that.

Comment: Welcome - glad it worked for you :)